# .replace or .push to alias - Vue router 4

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4

So I am trying to implement a feature to my website. Basically if you open a modal the router pushes(or .replace()) to the alias "/url-opened", so if somebody presses the back button in the browser it doesnt go to a other page, but to the "/url".

I already had this on my vue 2 project, but now with vue 3 it isn't working.